# Style a Div that uses forloop.counter

Tags: javascript, css, django

I have a contenteditable div fora  text area, and I want to style it

```
<div id="reply_body{{forloop.counter}}" name="reply_body"  contenteditable="true">Begin typing </div>
```

However, I am using {{forloop.counter}} because I am passing the information in the div to a javascript function. I.e.,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function copycontent(x)
{
document.getElementById('replies'+x).value=
document.getElementById('reply_body'+x).innerHTML;
};
</script>
```

So, my question is, how can I style this contenteditable div if part of the id is {{forloop.counter}}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class to style it:

```
<div id="..." class="reply">
```

CSS:

```
.reply {
    /* Your styles here */
}
```

ID's (denoted by `#` in CSS) have to be unique to an element, classes (denoted by `.` in CSS) can be used with multiple elements.